# Dynamically changing required value in primefaces input

Tags: javascript, primefaces

i want to simply change requaired value of some input depends on checkbox.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox
        id="check"
        value="#{cc.attrs.bean.bool}">
    <p:ajax update="test"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:panel id="test">
     <p:inputText id="input" required="#{cc.attrs.bean.bool}" label="required"/>
</p:panel>
```

when i am using this code after clicking chechbox there is no primefaces requried star after label(i mean if i set at begging true, star is always showed, when false star is always hidden), second it can be done whole on client side?

Important that when i am updatign whole form it works fine, but it clears all input, and i dont want to update all inputs.

Comment: Show all code form tag

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.

The clearing of your inputs could be caused by:

- your bean code reinitializing your variable(s) - check for any reinitialized variables
- if your bean is in @RequestScoped your whole state is being lost - in which case change the scope of your bean